# Should Content resolver insert happen in a background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, background, insert

I am unsure if there is a need to do processing in a background thread for content resolver insert functionality. I did it as a part of UI thread and the application runs file. But need to know if it is right calling inserts directly on ui thread.

Comment: primarily opinion-based ... I would say it is better to do this on background ... especially that no one says that ContentProvider have to be implemented on SQLite ... I can imagine CP which reads/writes directly to some web API

Comment: It is always better to place time-sensitive tasks in background thread.

Comment: run it in a background thread, nice helper to use: `android.content.AsyncQueryHandler` - the docs say: `"A helper class to help make handling asynchronous ContentResolver queries easier.`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend against it. Database writes are slow, and should be performed off the UI thread where possible. It may not be a problem for you now, but you may find that as your database grows or the nature of your application changes and you start writing more data, your UI thread will start to lag behind.

You may also find that this kind of operation in its current form might not run so smoothly on lower-end devices.

In addition to these issues, if you plan to share your database between multiple threads, concurrent writes can and will be blocked by the database lock to assure data integrity; this in turn may leave your UI thread hanging.

So, although it may not be a problem right now, you can save yourself a lot of time in the future by implementing and working with a design pattern that does ensure your transactions occur off the UI thread.

Whatever you do, make sure you give yourself a pat on the back for making this consideration in the first place!